# Why required attribute in Textarea is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, So I've already checked other questions but no one has the answer to the question I am asking. Just to be clear.

So, I am using **Materializecss** and **JQuery**. Here are the textarea fields I want to be required on condition!

```
<div class="col s12 input-field" style="margin-bottom:17px;margin-left:-12px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sslTypeToggle" name="sslType" />
    <label for="sslTypeToggle">I already have SSL Certificate.</label>
</div>
<div id="customSSL" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col s12 input-field">
        <textarea id="certificate" name="certificate" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="certificate">Paste Your Certificate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 input-field">
        <textarea id="privateKey" name="privateKey" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="privateKey">Paste Your Private Key</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 input-field">
        <textarea id="chain" name="chain" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="chain">Paste Your Chain File (CA Bundle)</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and Here is the Jquery I am using!

```
$('#sslTypeToggle').on('change',function()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
        $("#certificate").prop('required',true);
        $("#privateKey").prop('required',true);
        $("#chain").prop('required',true);
        $('#customSSL').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#certificate").prop('required',false);
        $("#privateKey").prop('required',false);
        $("#chain").prop('required',false);
        $('#customSSL').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

I don't know what's wrong. When I check with Inspect element, I can see the `required` attribute in `<textarea>` but Still, I can submit the form without entering anything in the field! Don't know what's wrong!

**UPDATE**: None of the answers worked. Maybe it is because I am Jquery and submitting form with JQuery too! Now, I am using Server Side validation!

Comment: In the rendered HTML, are there any whitespaces between the textarea open and close tags?

Comment: Between <textarea></textarea>, Nope!

Comment: _"but Still, I can submit the form without entering anything in the field!"_ Cannot reproduce

Comment: @guest271314, I want to say that even with `required` attribute added by Jquery function, I can submit the form without filling anything in textarea.

Comment: Cannot reproduce `<form>` submitting when no value is set at `<textarea>` elements. The `<form>` does not submit, here, when `required` attribute is set and no `.value` is set at `<textarea>` elements. Though since there is no expected pattern all that is necessary is a single space character `" "` to be input as `.value` at each `<textarea>` element for `<form>` to be valid

Answer (score 1):

You should node that if a field is hidden the required attribute isn't applied.

So all you really need to do put the `required` attribute on all of your textareas and bind the checkbox to show or hide the parent div:

```
$('#sslTypeToggle').click( function() {
    this.checked && $('#customSSL').fadeIn('fast') || $('#customSSL').fadeOut('fast');;
});
```

But to answer your question for some reason jQuery isn't setting the required property when selecting the element with the id selector. As a work around you can access the dom node by index and set the `.required` property directly.

Try  this

```
$(id)[0].required = checked;
```

```js
$('#sslTypeToggle').click( function() {
  var checked=this.checked;
  ["#certificate","#privateKey","#chain"].forEach(function(id)
  {
     $(id)[0].required = checked;
  });
  checked && $('#customSSL').fadeIn('fast') || $('#customSSL').fadeOut('fast');;
 
});
$('#sslTypeToggle').click();
$('form').submit(function() { alert('Form Submitted'); return false;});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col s12 input-field" style="margin-bottom:17px;margin-left:-12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sslTypeToggle" name="sslType"/>
      <label for="sslTypeToggle">I already have SSL Certificate.</label>
  </div>
  <div id="customSSL">
      <div class="col s12 input-field">
          <textarea id="certificate" name="certificate" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="certificate">Paste Your Certificate</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 input-field">
          <textarea id="privateKey" name="privateKey" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="privateKey">Paste Your Private Key</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 input-field">
          <textarea id="chain" name="chain" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="chain">Paste Your Chain File (CA Bundle)</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

*Note: The following line is for demo purposes only. Your form won't actually submit if you keep that line in your code.*

```
$('form').submit(function() { alert('Form Submitted'); return false;});
```